# display char that store in char array as int value

Tags: c

I have problem with this problem.
I have this assignment that I need to display character as numerical value.
Just like hotline phone number, e.g call `1-800-the-best`. it will show all the letter as number.

```
abc = 2, def = 3, ghi = 4, jkl = 5, mno = 6, pqrs = 7, tuv = 8, wxyz = 9.
```

I try using `atoi`, but that will ignore the numerical character and only convert alphabetical character.

Im using switch statement. there is no compiling error but somehow my output result is weird. here is my code

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#define num 11

int main(void)
{
    char ch;
    char number[11];
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;

    printf("please enter your phone number: \n");


    for(i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        scanf_s("%c", &ch);

        switch(ch)
        {
            case '0':
                number[i] = 0;
                break;

            case '1':
                number[i] = 1;
                break;

            case 'a': case 'b': case 'c':
                number[i] = 2;
                break;

            case 'd': case 'e': case 'f':
                number[i] = 3;
                break;

            case 'g': case 'h': case 'i':
                number[i] = 4;
                break;

            case 'j': case 'k': case 'l':
                number[i] = 5;
                break;

            case 'm': case 'n': case 'o':
                number[i] = 6;
                break;

            case 'p': case 'q': case 'r': case 's':
                number[i] = 7;
                break;

            case 't': case 'u': case 'v':
                number[i] = 8;
                break;

            case 'w': case 'x': case 'y': case 'z':
                number[i] = 9;
                break;
        }
    }

    printf("the phone number you enter is: ");

    for(j = 0; j < num; j++)
    {
        printf("%d", number[j]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

When i enter each char as numbers e.g: `1 2 3 4 5 6` the output result is

> 1-52-52-52-52-52-52-52-52-52-52-52.

If I enter each char as alphabet e.g: `a b c d e f` the output result is

> 2-522-522-523-523-523.

I wonder what I did wrong.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please read [ask], and show your code.

Comment: `int dialnum[128] = { 0, 0, ... 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, ... };` The first `2` is at `dialnum['A']` and the array can handle numeral values, lowercase, and special chars too.

Comment: thank you. lemme try this method.

Comment: Please note that this is a question and answer site, not a
code writing service. If you [edit] your question to
describe what you have tried so far and where you are stuck,
then we can try to help with specific problems. You should
also read [ask].

Comment: Im sorry, so here is what i am trying to do. instead of following weather vane method, i use switch statement. there is no compiling error, but my output result is weird.

Answer (score 0):

you forgot to tell it what to do with number inputs. You need to add more case statements, one for each number, like so:

```
 #include<stdio.h>
 #include<string.h>
 #define num 11

 int main(void)
{
    char ch;
    char number[11];
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;

    printf("please enter your phone number: \n");


    for(i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        scanf("%c", &ch); // changed from scanf_s() to scanf()

        switch(ch)
       {
        case '0':
            number[i] = 0;
            break;

        case '1':
            number[i] = 1;
            break;

        case 'a': case 'b': case 'c':case '2':
            number[i] = 2;
            break;

        case 'd': case 'e': case 'f': case '3':
            number[i] = 3;
            break;

        case 'g': case 'h': case 'i': case '4':
            number[i] = 4;
            break;

        case 'j': case 'k': case 'l': case '5':
            number[i] = 5;
            break;

        case 'm': case 'n': case 'o': case '6':
            number[i] = 6;
            break;

        case 'p': case 'q': case 'r': case 's': case '7':
            number[i] = 7;
            break;

        case 't': case 'u': case 'v': case '8':
            number[i] = 8;
            break;

        case 'w': case 'x': case 'y': case 'z': case '9':
            number[i] = 9;
            break;
       }
    }

    printf("the phone number you enter is: ");

    for(j = 0; j < num; j++)
    {
        printf("%d", number[j]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This compiled and ran correctly once the extra cases were entered. However you will also want to deal with inputs that are none of these, the best way would be to add

```
default: printf("Number/letter not entered\n"); break;
```

This will deal with things such as `.,#` etc

Edited to show full program.

Comment: I assume that people will not press other key when they dial a number, that is why I did not make default case for othey key. It is bugging me that why is that the output is not right.

Comment: ah, i see what i did wrong here. thank you. let me edit my code

Comment: I also changed `scanf_s` to `scanf`. I thought that was a typo as it would not compile for me with `scanf_s`. I just edited my answer to show the full program.

Comment: Ok i just found out that scanf_s is a windows function, [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w40768et.aspx) , which i why it would not compile for me, however with `scanf` it still works fine for me

Comment: im using visual studio as my compiler, so when i use scanf, it will complle but it gives me warning, then when i run the code and get user input, once i enter the value, my program just quit and show error message